# Comparing a csv file and a text file

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to programming.
I'm trying to read a CSV file which looks like this:

> GVHN_Brazil_GGXS,0 
> TTYU_Germany_HLZ,5

etc..
(the number is an actual count)

and compare it with a text file that looks like this:

> GVHN_Brazil_GGXS;50;100
> TTYU_Germany_HLZ;30;70
> etc..

(the numbers here being two limits which will have different actions)

I'm trying to find the "best practice" to read each count from the CSV file and compare with each unique limit in the text file and haven't gotten further than being able to read both files.

EDIT: New problem, with pistolpete's help I got what I wanted with the exception that the numbers in the files don't seem to become integers so it messes up the comparison process.

For instance, I set all limits to 50 and 100 to test it, and when the count is 10, it's works, but if it's 7 or 8 it triggers the 50 limit and when the count was 15 it triggers the 100 limit.

As if 7 becomes 70 and 15 becomes 150 or something like this

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please edit your question and add additional example lines from both the `csv` and `txt` files. It is difficult to understand the structure from the examples you have included.

Comment: Yes, sorry didn't figure out how to make it two separate lines hence the "\newline". I changed the text so it's basically the same as the actual files but changed country and the abbreviations

Comment: Both of these files are essentially CSV (character-separated variables) aka delimited files. Both can be handled by the Python [csv](https://realpython.com/python-csv/) module, using different delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) with a ";" delimiter for the text file. Then you can loop over the rows of each file and compare the fields you care about.

```py
import csv


with open("csv_file.csv") as csv_file:
    with open("text_file.txt") as text_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=("name", "actual_count"))
        text_reader = csv.DictReader(text_file, fieldnames=("name", "limit_1", "limit_2"), delimiter=";")

        for csv_row, text_row in zip(csv_reader, text_reader):
            # example comparison, replace this with whatever comparison logic you care about
            if int(csv_row["actual_count"]) < int(text_row["limit_1"]):
                do_something()
```

Comment: Thank you, however now the count- and limit-keys seem to become strings, as I've set the first limit to 50 and the second to 100 and a count with 7 or 8 shows as bigger than either one of the limits. How do I convert the keys(?) to integers? ©pistolpete

Comment: You can simply cast to int. See my edit for an example